# SQL Server trigger execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Say I have an UPDATE trigger on `tableA` that inserts a new record into `tableB`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertIntoTableB
ON tableA
FOR UPDATE 
AS
   INSERT INTO tableB (...) VALUES (...)  
GO
```

I then run these statements sequentially. Will the second UPDATE statement (UPDATE `tableB`) work OK? (i.e. wait for the trigger on table A to fully execute)

```
UPDATE tableA
SET ...
WHERE key = 'some key'

UPDATE tableB
SET ...
WHERE key = 'newly inserted key from trigger'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is subject to the [`nested triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191520.aspx) server configuration, see [Using Nested Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx):

> Both DML and DDL triggers are nested
>   when a trigger performs an action that
>   initiates another trigger. These
>   actions can initiate other triggers,
>   and so on. DML and DDL triggers can be
>   nested up to 32 levels. You can
>   control whether AFTER triggers can be
>   nested through the `nested triggers`
>   server configuration option. INSTEAD
>   OF triggers (only DML triggers can be
>   INSTEAD OF triggers) can be nested
>   regardless of this setting.

When a trigger on table A fires and inside the trigger table B is updated, the trigger on table B runs immediately. The Table A trigger did *not* finish, it is blocked in waiting for the UPDATE statement to finish, which in turn  waits for the Table B trigger to finish. However, the updates to table A have already occurred (assuming a normal AFTER trigger) and querying the Table A from the table B's trigger *will* see the updates.

Comment: sorry I may have been unclear at first, but there is only a single trigger and that is on tableA, I've updated my post accordingly

Comment: I see. The first update statement will not complete before it's trigger has returned. At the moment the second UPDATE start executing, you are absolutely 100% guaranteed that the previous statement has finished, including any triggers it may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

If the updates are sequentially coded into the UPDATE trigger of A then yes.

Comment: Well in the UPDATE trigger of tableA, there's is a single INSERT INTO tableB statement and the UPDATE tableA, and UPDATE tableB statements above are executed sequentially

Comment: I think you will be ok then. Best thing would be to test it.